# Golang gorm ORM avoid auto creating tables and columns

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using Golang and Gorm to connect to a MySQL database. I have noticed that tables or columns are being auto-created when they do not exist in the database (similar to auto DDL in Hibernate). I would like to disable this feature, but I am unsure how to do so. Can you please suggest a way to disable this auto-creation feature?

Comment: This is because you are calling AutoMigrate method, if you couldn't fix this please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Tables/columns are auto created when [db.AutoMigrate](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Auto-Migration) is called, skip this call if you don't want them to be created/modified.